# Editting Detail Within Wordpress Footer

Tags: wordpress, footer

A friend of mine is working a design, and she wants to add some extra details to the footer. However the links to the theme she also wants to edit ;

http://www.certaxnorthampton.co.uk/

Please can you tell me where that is displaying the data from? As i have checked the footer.php and it appears to not be located in there.

thanks
Kirsty

Comment: What do you see in `footer.php`? Is there a way to download the theme from somewhere, since we can't just know how the theme is structured :)

Comment: it would be better if you paste your footer code as well

Comment: Hi all, I will see if i can obtain this information and respond shortly.